# media9 in tables

Tags: tables, media9

I am using the `media9` package to embed sound files in my documents. This works quite fine in ordinary text, but when trying to run the same commands in a tabular environment, LaTeX apparently ends up in some kind of loop. In fact, the compilation appears to go on forever; however, it does give me the error message (while still trying desperately to compile):

> ! Improper alphabetic constant.
>    
>                      \unskip 
>   l.26    \listen{test.mp3}{hello}

The code I'm using is:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,geometry,graphicx,amstext,tipa}

\usepackage{media9}
\newcommand*\listen[2]{ % listen to the file named #1, but write out #2
    \includemedia[
    addresource=#1,
    transparent,
    flashvars={
        source=#1
        &autoPlay=true
        &hideBar=true
    },
    ]{#2}{APlayer.swf}
}

\begin{document}

\listen{test.mp3}{hello} %this works fine

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \listen{test.mp3}{hello} %this causes a painful death
        & what
            & is\\
    the
        & problem
            & here
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your definition (after a few expansions) has `&` at the top level so messes up the table cells, add `{}` to hide them:

```
\newcommand*\listen[2]{{%% listen to the file named #1, but write out #2
    \includemedia[
    addresource=#1,
    transparent,
    flashvars={
        source=#1
        &autoPlay=true
        &hideBar=true
    },
    ]{#2}{APlayer.swf}%
}}
```

Note you also had spurious space token at the start and end of the definition which I've also removed.

Comment: Wow, I had never imagined that the answer would be that simple. Thanks a lot! :-)